# Autoconf rejected by C++11 library accepted by compiler, reject by preprocessor

Tags: c++, c++11, autoconf

I'm trying to integrate [rapidcheck](https://github.com/emil-e/rapidcheck) into an existing C++ codebase. The README says it requires C++11 and relies heavily on its features. The existing codebase uses automake to build all of the dependencies. Here is how I am adding the dependency into `configure.ac`:

```
  CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -Wall -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -std=c++11"
  CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -I/home/chris/dev/rapidcheck/include"
  CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -I/home/chris/dev/rapidcheck/include/rapidcheck"
  AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
      [rapidcheck.h],
      [AC_CHECK_LIB([rapidcheck], [main],[], [])],
      [])
```

Here is the error I am getting when I run the configure script:

```
checking rapidcheck.h usability... yes
checking rapidcheck.h presence... no
configure: WARNING: rapidcheck.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
configure: WARNING: rapidcheck.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for rapidcheck.h... yes
checking for main in -lrapidcheck... no
```

contents of `config.log`

```
3501 configure:22873: checking rapidcheck.h usability
3502 configure:22873: g++ -std=c++11 -c -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wall -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -std=c++11 -I/home/chris/dev/rapidcheck/include -I/home/chris     /dev/rapidcheck/include/rapidcheck  -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS conftest.cpp >&5
3503 configure:22873: $? = 0
3504 configure:22873: result: yes
3505 configure:22873: checking rapidcheck.h presence
3506 configure:22873: g++ -std=c++11 -E  -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS conftest.cpp
3507 conftest.cpp:58:24: fatal error: rapidcheck.h: No such file or directory
3508 compilation terminated.
```

I think it has something to do with not having an up to date C++ compiler.

Here is the version of C++ I have installed:

```
chris@chris:~/dev/bitcoin$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Which *I THINK* is C++11 compatible.

Comment: gcc 4.9 does have reasonable, but not complete, C++11 support.

Comment: So I need to upgrade to another version? What is the minimum version I should upgrade to?

Comment: I'd say 5.3. The current version of gcc is 6.1

Comment: Preprocessor flags(like `-I`) should be set with `CPPFLAGS` not `CXXFLAGS`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I updated to 5.3 and I still have the same error. @Galik if I change to using `CPPFLAGS` automake does not find `rapidcheck.h` at all

Comment: There's no `rapidcheck.h` in the C++ Standard. It's not related to C++11.

Comment: @Ruslan how does this differ from what I am currently doing in `configure.ac`? What do I need to add?

Comment: I think setting `CXXFLAGS` in `configure.ac` is discouraged. Try instead setting the environment variable `CPATH` in your shell, e.g. `export CPATH=/home/chris/dev/rapidcheck/include:/home/chris/dev/rapidcheck/include/rapidcheck`

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1508393/3807729

Comment: A different person compiling your software may have installed the `rapidcheck.h` library in a different location. So it is up to the person calling `configure` to supply flags to search in non-standard locations.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `automake`, it has to do with `autoconf`.

In particular, you should be able to ignore this warning in general because autoconf accepts the compiler output better than the preprocessor. As someone already said in the comments, `CPPFLAGS` should be used to pass `-I` flags for the preprocessor to find the headers, but in this case it's really not that important, given that those flags should not be set in `configure.ac` at all (but rather be passed from the outside since the install location is defined by the user.)